# Read() не работает (PascalABC.NET)

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Процедура read(s2) не выполняется

Код

```
var
  s1, s2: string;
  h1, m1: integer;
begin
  read(s1);
  h1 := Strtoint(s1[1:3]);
  m1 := StrtoInt(s1[4:6]);
  read(s2);
  write(h1, m1);
end.
```

Работает так

```
12:25 (спросил s1)
1225
```

А надо так

```
12:25
(спрашивает s2)
1225
```

Comment: `ReadLn(s1);`...`ReadLn(s2);`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Answer (score 0):

Читайте строку:

```
ReadLn(s1);
...
ReadLn(s2);
```